# Using React Router the <Redirect /> Does not redirect anywhere, but why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router, jsx

I have been trying to Unsuccesfully redirect a user back ho "/" or "/home" after registration is done inside .then() , eveyrthing inside promise executes EXCEPT the redirection. I used just if(true) to test it, and It does go to that point, because I can get the console.log to display text there, but just Redirect is fruitless..

const createUserWithEmailAndPasswordHandler =(event) => {
event.preventDefault();

```
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(signUp.email, signUp.pw1).then((authData) =>{
        console.log("authData" + authData);
        addUserDataToDb({
            email: signUp.email,
            username: signUp.username,
        });
        if (true) {
            return <Redirect to='/home' />;
        }
    })
        .catch((error) => {
            setSignUp({
                ...signUp,
                error: error,
            });
            console.error(error);
        });

    setSignUp(INITIAL_STATE);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Redirect` need to be rendered in order to work! You can try using `history.push` instead.

Comment: Oh my lord! You helped me! Thank you! I really spent a long time trying to figure out why it was not rendering! For anyone else who had same issue in the future use : 
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
let history = useHistory();

 const handleRedirect = () =>{
  history.push("/")
 }

and then call it when needed! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

What you actually doing is you return a react Component. And if I'm not wrong what you're trying to achieve is to send him '/home' and in that case you're going to need to use the history object that the Router component provides to your component via props if it's a direct child of the Router component, if it's not a direct child of the Router component you'll have to use hooks if you're using function components or HOC if you're using Class components.
Example for function component.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}


Example for Class component.

  import { withRouter } from "react-router";
  class MyComponent extends React.Component {
onClickHandler(){
this.props.history.push('/home')
}
   render() {
     return <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Hello</button>;
   }
}
export default withRouter(MyComponent)
```