# React Redirect not redirecting

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to redirect the user to another page when logged in by returning `Redirect`, but the page doesn't redirect, and renders nothing.

Here's the general structure of the code:

```
const LandingPage = () => {

  const loginData = useContext(loginStorage)
  const {isLoggedIn, openSignIn} = loginData
  
  if(isLoggedIn){
      return <Redirect to="/home" />
  }

  return (
    <div> 
        <button onClick={openSignIn}>login</button>
        landing page...
    </div>
  )
}
```

`isLoggedIn` is from context, and `openSignIn()` is a function that opens a popup component. 
Is it's because the state isLoggedIn is from context? 
Thanks in advance.

-------EDIT-------- 
Ok, I know it's been a while, but I just wanted to update the results. 
So in the end I wasn't able to replicate the same issue because it simply took a bit too long. 
But my colleague figured out that passing a route object instead of a string, like `<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/home'}} />`, would do the trick

Comment: This question has already been answered. here's a link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64371190/using-react-router-the-redirect-does-not-redirect-anywhere-but-why/64371458#64371458

Comment: [This question has already been answered here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64371190/using-react-router-the-redirect-does-not-redirect-anywhere-but-why/64371458#64371458)

Comment: ok.if can display sample code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) .it's great.

Comment: @IdanGigi I don't see how that's the same issue. `Redirect` is rendered, it's just not redirecting as it should.

Comment: @A.R.SEIF I'll try my best to make something similar, it's an overall structure from a rather large project

Comment: ok.it's sample code

Comment: Try to place Redirect inside the JSX with ternary condition